# How can I preview AWS Glue jobs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I´m want to use Glue to extract data from an RDS PostgresDB, transform/clean it and load into an S3 Bucket so I can use Athena and Quicksight to visualize the data and create reports.

I´m currently authoring the Glue job for the data cleanup (remove NULL values and such things). But I can see no easy way to preview the job script results. I can only see the results in the S3 bucket after running the complete job. And running the job takes at least 10 minutes to start, and a few more to finish. So I have a roundtrip time of about 15 minutes to see if my code is correct. Is this supposed to be the workflow here? Am I missing anything?

I´m new to the whole BI/data stuff. Maybe I´m following the wrong approach. I want to visualize data from RDS in Quicksight and need to do some data cleanup first. Any other approaches that make sense for this scenario? (we are talking about a small dataset of about a few 100MBs)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into notebooks. You can set them up in the AWS Glue Console. They give you an interactive way of writing your code before you put the script into a Glue Script. No big difference between Sagemaker (Juypter) and Zeppelin notebooks for standard cases, guess its down to our taste.

In general, especially with small datasets, a local development environment might work out for you as well and gives you even more freedom. For larger datasets a common practise is to get a sample of only a few hundred records so it can be processed instantaneous. Helps a lot during development.

And last: Not sure why to go away from Postgres. What kind of analysis do you want to do you can't do in the Relational world? Also, why don't do the clean-up in the DB?

Comment: Ah! Things start to make sense. Now I need to figure out how to get this running. From the AWS Glue/Sagemaker side this looks like I need to start at least a few new instances (Glue Dev Endpoint, Sagemaker Notebook). But for now it looks like a easier-to-setup solution than running my own notebook server. 
About your questions: The postgres DB schema/data is currently out of my influence. I need to work with the data as is. Actually I only need to do cleanup nulls and a bit of type transformation to facilitate visualization. Any pointers how I could achieve this without a "big" ETL pipe?

Comment: you could either create a new schema under your control if that's possible or e.g. work with views